# ipyton startup script syntax error

Tags: ipython, startup

I would like to always log ipython commandline and output to a file in append mode. On reading the file under `.ipython/profile_default/startup` README

```
$ cat README 
This is the IPython startup directory

.py and .ipy files in this directory will be run *prior* to any code or files specified
via the exec_lines or exec_files configurables whenever you load this profile.

Files will be run in lexicographical order, so you can control the execution order of files
with a prefix, e.g.::

    00-first.py
    50-middle.py
    99-last.ipy
```

I tried adding a file first.py with below contents

```
  logstart -o -r -t logs/ipython.log 'append'
```

`logstart` is a magic command. I am getting below error when I am trying to start ipython

```
  File "/home/mtk/.ipython/profile_default/startup/00-first.py", line 1
    logstart -o -r -t logs/ipython.log 'append'
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: To use magic commands in startup files, use a `.ipy` extension. `.py` files have to be regular Python code,  without IPython special syntax.

Answer (score 1):

"Thomas K" comment also looks like a solution, but here is different solution that I found myself

As he stated correct, we can only have python code in *.py file in the startup folder, I replaced my earlier text with below. Magic commands can be invoked using `run_line_magic` method

```
get_ipython().run_line_magic(u"logstart", u"-o -r /home/mt/Dropbox/a/logs/ipython_log.py append")
get_ipython().run_line_magic(u"logstate", "")
```